# Downloading through Ubuntu Software Center gives an error

Tags: software-center, downloads

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and downloading with the Ubuntu Software Center gives an error (There seems to be a programming error in *aptdaemon*).  I haven't done anything weird, did not try to install *Wine* or anything. No idea what happened.

What can i do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use Synaptic Package Manager to search for broken packages. Then use it to fix/upgrade the packages. A

```
sudo apt-get install
```

should get it sorted out for you.